# M2 - How to hide Out of Stock products in "Who Bought this Also Bought" Aheadworks extension?

Tags: magento2, extensions

Does anyone know how to hide Out of Stock products in "Who Bought this Also Bought" Aheadworks extension? Or any tips that will help me with this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

File: **app/code/local/AW/Relatedproducts/Block/Relatedproducts.php**

Method: `_returnSortedArray`
and replace the string

```
$array[] = $product;
```

with

```
if($product->isSaleable() === true ) {
     $array[] = $product;
}
```